# C# Getting return value from Elapsed Time Event

Tags: c#, event-handling, return-value, elapsedtime

Hi I have a similar problem to an old thread that I still can't work around 
([Pass a return value back through an EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446256/pass-a-return-value-back-through-an-eventhandler)) . I am eventually trying to implement a timer that will calculate velocity at even intervals so I require the Elapsed Time Event to return some kind of value. I've tried using global variables but the event doesn't seem to change the variable. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

```
namespace Timer_Label
{
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static int _stringHolder;

    public static int StringHolder
    {
        get { return _stringHolder; }
        set { _stringHolder = value; }
    }
}

    public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 500;
        myTimer.Start();


        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(GlobalVariables.StringHolder));
    }

  public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {   
        GlobalVariables.StringHolder = "1";                                 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's highly improbable that the timer will have expired by the time the code reaches your MessageBox.Show statement.

Try placing a Thread.Sleep(1000) call between myTimer.Start() and MessageBox.Show(). This should give the timer time to elapse and execute your DisplayTimeEvent handler.

Eventually, you will need to take into account the fact that the System.Timer.Timer class executes its callback in a background thread, so changes that you make in DisplayTimeEvent will need to be synchronized.