# How to trigger an event with a variable change

Tags: c#, string, forms, object

I get two return variables from a user control back. 
I want to use these variables in the main form and in a next user control. 
Unfortunately I can't seem to get them into my main form.

User control where the variables come from:

```
 try
 {
     this.Visible = false;
     textBox1.Clear();
     textBox2.Clear();
     Dashboard frm2 = new Dashboard(name , rechte);
 }
```

And the main Form receives the variables but I don´t get how to continue accessing them (like label3.Text = .... ):

```
    public Dashboard(object name, object rechte)
    {
        this.BN =Convert.ToString(name);
        this.brechte =Convert.ToString(rechte);
    }
```

Comment: You need to use a Model. Google MVC (Model View Controller pattern)

Comment: What issue you are facing in doing `label3.Text = this.brechte`

Comment: Web form? HTML form? Windows form? What kind of form?

Comment: It looks like your user control is creating a new form?  That seems backwards

Comment: Its a windows form. The idea is that the main windows form opens and closes user controls and exchances variable among them. But it doesnt work to use this vairables

Comment: Unrelated: Why make the ctor args `object` when you need strings?

Comment: You probably want to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446256/pass-a-return-value-back-through-an-eventhandler