# How can we use event and delegation model to pass output from a method in first class to another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

This is my first file, form1.cs:

```
namespace EventsNDelegates
  {
   public delegate void DelEventHandler();

   public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
    public event DelEventHandler add;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        add += new DelEventHandler(Initiate);
        //invoke the event  
        add();
    }
    public void Initiate()
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Hello";
    } 
  }
}
```

and this is my second file class1.cs:

```
namespace EventsNDelegates
{
class Class1
{

}
}
```

and this is my form design:

[image]

Now currently on button click the event is firing in form1.

What I need is that the events gets fired on button click form form1.cs in class1.cs and the output gets displayed in the textbox of form1.

Comment: If class1 doesn't have any reference to form1, it can't do it directly. But I assume there is another class (maybe simply Program) that holds references for both classes; you'll have to work in this class to transfer the information.

Comment: I dont understand. You want to invoke event in form1 from class1, or subscribe on event in class1 and invoke this in form1?

Comment: both these classes are under the same namespace. the form is in form1.cs where we also have the text box and button. now when I click the button in form1.cs it should fire an event in class1.cs and I want a loop to run in that event (like a counter till 1 to 20) and I want all those values 1 to 20 get displayed in text box of form1.cs @Kilazur

Comment: @IvanKishchenko I want all the events to be invoked by button click in form1 inside class1.cs. now class1.cs will have a loop which will have a counter. I need all tose values to be printed inside text box of form1.cs

Comment: An event works like a newspaper subscription. The customer subscribes to the event and the newspaper will be delivered. Then the customer decides what to do with that (he implements a handler routine) Now you have to decide who is the newspaper-delivery-guy and who is the customer in your case. If you have figured that out. rephrase your question please

Comment: @MongZhu form1 is customer and class1 is handler. I want the click event on form1.cs being handled at class1.cs and response from class1.cs with output back to form1.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to subscribe on event from another class, and show result in form1 class you can try this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Foo(Form1 form) // Method with your cycle in class1
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var str = i.ToString(); // Write iterator in local inloop variable for correct capture in lambda
            form.add += () =>  // subscribe on form1 event
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                return str;
            };
        }
    }
}

public delegate string DelEventHandler(); // change return type to string

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event DelEventHandler add;
    public Class1 class1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        class1 = new Class1();
        class1.Foo(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var handler in add.GetInvocationList().Cast<DelEventHandler>()) // Get all subscribers for correct invoke
        {
            textBox1.Text = handler(); // invoke all subscribers and write result to textBox1
            Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass an instance of form1 in a class1 to sign up for its event. Also, you should not simply call an event. You should be [call all subscribers of event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237001/when-an-event-has-multiple-subscribers-how-do-i-get-the-return-value-for-each-s) on form1 button click. Do not forget to copy the iterator in the capture within the loop in order to avoid [incorrect operations](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88e68dfe-5ca0-46e0-83fa-0038f624d04f/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot?forum=csharpgeneral) in class1 cycle.

Comment: everything is good, excepts it prints 0 to 99 all together. what I need is a counter. like 0 comes goes 1 comes and followed till 99 and stop.

Comment: I updated my answer. Added 'Thread.Sleep' to simulate a delay. And added 'Refresh' method to redraw the form. But it is better to use an asynchronous call in such cases. You mean it?

Comment: ah @Ivan Kishchenko it refresh but the old content does not goes.

I need the output as:
0 then
1 then
.
.
at last only 100 in the textbox

But am getting 0 1 2 3 ... 100 all together

Comment: Edit answer. You can change plus-assignment to assignment for textBox1: textBox1.Text = handler();